# Bash script - String compare does not seem to work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have an input file with contents in the following format:

```
ABCD     XYZAB   1234
PQRSTUV  STU     SKIP
LMN      OPRQM   8966
RSTUV    OPM     SKIP
TUV      ZXU     SKIP
```

I want to parse this file and output it to a new file such that, rows with their last column as "SKIP" do not appear in the final output file, as below:

```
ABCD     XYZAB   1234
LMN      OPRQM   8966
```

To process the above, I wrote up the following shell script:

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3
do
    if [ "$col3" != "SKIP" ]
    then
    printf "%s %s %s\n" "$col1" "$col2" "$col3";
    fi
done <input.txt > output.txt
```

But the above script just doesn't seem to work, my output file still continues to have all the rows, with "SKIP" in their last column. I don't understand why the "conditional" is failing ?

Thanks,
vj

Comment: Same for me; ran on CentOS and MacOS.

Comment: That is odd, I am quite sure..  I don't see this working for me :(

Comment: Does this work for you? `awk '{ if ($3 != "SKIP") print $0 }' input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: I don't have access to my dev machine now. I will try and update this post. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could your file contain non-ASCII whitespace between the columns?

Comment: In fact it has tabs in between the columns... Could that be an issue ? But when I echo "$col3" I get SKIP.

Comment: `egrep 'SKIP$' input-file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems that though the script is correct, the input file being edited was in Windows environment. As a result the line endings were "\r" and not "\n". So, there was a mismatch there. So, the conditional check failed as well. Once I converted the line endings to UNIX format, the output was obtained as desired. Thanks for everyone's help.

Vj

Comment: That would have been my guess. FTR: Windows encodes line endings as `\r\n`, not just as `\r`. Otherwise your script wouldn't have found a single match, because the entire input file would have been read as a single line. Due to the `\r\n` the last field in was read as `SKIP\r` and thus didn't match the string `SKIP`.

Answer (score 0):

VJ - I do not see any problem with your script. I pasted your code and input and the result was exactly what you want. See proof below from my laptop "ttt":

```
[ttt:/m/temp/stack] cat vjvj 

    while read -r col1 col2 col3
    do
        if [ "$col3" != "SKIP" ]
        then
        printf "%s %s %s\n" "$col1" "$col2" "$col3";
        fi
    done  output.txt

[ttt:/m/temp/stack] cat input.txt 
ABCD     XYZAB   1234
PQRSTUV  STU     SKIP
LMN      OPRQM   8966
RSTUV    OPM     SKIP
TUV      ZXU     SKIP
[ttt:/m/temp/stack] cat output.txt
ABCD XYZAB 1234
LMN OPRQM 8966
[ttt:/m/temp/stack] cat /etc/lsb-release

    DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=13
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=maya
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 13 Maya"

[ttt:/m/temp/stack]
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. Several of us already commented that it works as expected.

Comment: When I posted, I don't believe there were comments . If I missed the comments, my apologies .